# Problems with LNK2001 when create Unit Test for C code

Tags: c, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm trying to configure **Unit Test** for **C code** with a **Native Unit Test project** in Visual Studio 2017. But have some issues with **Linker Tools Error LNK2001** when include functions from other libs or even other **h files** in same project(lib).

*There is no problem with linking when build lib´s, without the Unit Test project.*

It's works fine when I do unit test against one **h** and **c-file** that have no other depends. But soon as I include calls to function in other h files. I get problems with linking.

It seams like mytest project(c++), don't have the same access as projects(c).

I have no idea how to solve the error. But I can added more information about problem, if need just ask and I'll try to get it.

Comment: Please fell free to edit the question, if you feel I have expressed myself bit strange. Insted of dislike it.

Comment: You need to link against the same libraries and set the same include directories as the project you're testing, if you depend on these libraries. See also [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls#objectRef) (related to DLLs, but should give you a pointer).

Comment: I have include all libs as references in mytest project also included libs in Configuration Properties | VC++ Directories. I also think that I done everything that your link says.

Comment: Do you have the unit test in a different solution by any chance...

Comment: No, everything is in same solution, but different project. Have 4 Static library's in solution and mytest project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to explain to the C++ compiler in Visual Studio a C header is coming when you include the declaration for the C function. So your `myTes.cpp` should begins with:

```
extern "C" {
#include "somecode.h"
}
```

`static_lib1.h`should contain something like:

```
 #ifndef STATIC_LIB1_H_
 #define STATIC_LIB1_H_

 SWord doSomeThing();

 #endif
```

I think this should fix your problem **Linker Tools Error LNK2001**.

Comment: It solved my problem. Did not expect that  C++ would not understand C code.